# WSO2 ESB out sequence showing empty response for JSON request

Tags: json, rest, wso2, payload, wso2-esb

I am trying to send this JSON payload:

```
{
    "ExtReference": "12345678",
    "MemberSubType":{
                    "MemberSubTypeId":"20",
                    "Name":"DD"},
    "Region": "",
    "PersonalDetails": {
        "FirstName": "arisan",
        "LastName": "sample",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "DateOfBirth": "",
        "GenderType": "",
        "SalutationType":"",
        "MemberStatus":""
    },
    "Address": [{
        "AddressLine1": "vfhd",
        "AddressLine2": "jdfvbgkjfds",
        "HouseName": "",
        "HouseNumber": "",
        "Street": "",
        "Locality": "",
        "City": "kolkata",
        "County": "",
        "Zip": "43543",
        "CountryId": "NZ",
        "PostBox": "",
        "PostBoxNumber": ""
    }],
    "ContactDetails": [{
        "Email": "sdjk@hs.com",
        "Phone": "378654839674",
        "MobilePhone": "87425343287",
        "Fax": "345435",
        "ContactDetailsType": ""
    }],
    "ExtensionData": [{
                    "PropertyName":"",
                    "PropertyValue":""
                    }]
```

}

The payload is getting logged properly in ESB logs. But in out sequence, I am not getting the desired results at all. I wanted the response in below format:

```
{"Success":true,"Message":"null","Data":1888304}
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
{"Success":false,"Message":"The resource submitted contains no data: please check the information is correct and try again","Data":null}
```

I have verified the the logged JSON payload from an external rest client and it gives me the correct response.

Here is the proxy code I use to send the JSON payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SNIPCustomerTest"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" separator=", **Incoming_Request**"/>
         <header xmlns:cus="http://www.example.org/customerWSO2/"
                 name="cus:passport"
                 scope="default"
                 action="remove"/>
               <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                  <format>
                                    {
        "ExtReference": "$8",
        "MemberSubType":{
"MemberSubTypeId":"20",
"Name":"DD"},
        "Region": "",        
        "PersonalDetails": {
            "FirstName": "$9",
            "LastName": "sample",
            "MiddleName": "",
            "DateOfBirth": "",
            "GenderType": "",
            "SalutationType":"",
            "MemberStatus":""
        },
        "Address": [{
            "AddressLine1": "$1",
            "AddressLine2": "$2",
            "HouseName": "",
            "HouseNumber": "",
            "Street": "",
            "Locality": "",
            "City": "$3",
            "County": "",
            "Zip": "$15",
            "CountryId": "NZ",
            "PostBox": "",
            "PostBoxNumber": ""
        }],
        "ContactDetails": [{
            "Email": "$5",
            "Phone": "$10",
            "MobilePhone": "$7",
            "Fax": "$6",
            "ContactDetailsType": ""
        }],
        "ExtensionData": [{
"PropertyName":"",
"PropertyValue":""
}]
}
                                    </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:addr1/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:addr2/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:city/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:country/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:email/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:fax/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:mobile/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:nSInternalID/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:name/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:phone/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:salesRep/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:state/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:territory/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:url/text()"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml"
                          expression="//cus:addParentCustToJADERequest/cus:parentCustData/cus:zip/text()"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
               <log separator=", ****JSON_Request****">
                  <property name="toJSON" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
               </log>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <http method="post" uri-template="https://uat.snipp.ie/scholasticapi/member"/>
                     <property name="Authorization"
                               value="78ca6121-763c-41c6-8dfe-d73e761b9989;https://uat.snipp.ie/scholasticapi/member;Fri Jul 24 2015 15:03:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time);idiuOEsgiVQU2cJj2p2nawCEHGtyN1cIWzpHP+NlJm4="
                               scope="transport"/>
                     <property name="Content-Type" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <log separator=", **Incoming_Response**" description="Incoming_Response">
            <property name="toJSON" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   name="Code"
                   expression="//soapenv:Fault/faultcode"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   name="Message"
                   expression="//soapenv:Fault/faultstring"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <enrich>
            <source type="inline" clone="true">
               <SoapFault xmlns="">
                  <Code/>
                  <Message/>
               </SoapFault>
            </source>
            <target type="body"/>
         </enrich>
         <enrich>
            <source type="property" clone="true" property="Code"/>
            <target xpath="//SoapFault/Code"/>
         </enrich>
         <enrich>
            <source type="property" clone="true" property="Message"/>
            <target xpath="//SoapFault/Message"/>
         </enrich>
         <send/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/myresources/Customer.wsdl"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: could you please attach your proxy definition?

Comment: I have already attached the portion for ur help...but still if it is not suffice then please find it below my question.

Comment: what is the purpose of using respond mediator in outSequence?

Comment: I added that just to get the response in SOAPUI....don't consider that please.

Comment: @AriSan , did you try removing the <respond/> mediator from outSequence ?